# Getting all suffixes of a string in c++

Tags: c++, c, string

In C one can declare a char array, create a pointer to a specific location in the array, and dereference it to get a suffix in the specified position:

```
char str[6] = "SLEEP";
char* pointer = &(str[1]);
printf("%s\n", pointer);
```

The above code will print

```
LEEP
```

which is the suffix of "SLEEP" in position 1. Now is there a way to do something similar in C++ without using the substr method as it produces a completely new string and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: So, C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Use an iterator pair.

Comment: std::string str("SLEEP");
char* pointer = &(str.c_str()[1]);
printf("%s\n", pointer);

Comment: @madnut, Except it's not modifiable.

Comment: @chris Technically it is modifiable but lets say it shouldent be modified this way :)

Comment: whytheman: You may like to see [this code](http://codepad.org/uoG5u70Y)

Comment: @madnut: `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, so after you fix `pointer`'s type, it's not modifiable.  Type-casting to forcibly modify it is underfined behaviour in C++03.  Anyway - as is and assuming a non-modifiable result is all that's needed - it's a good solution and portable across C++03 and C++11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do exactly what you've already done.

```
char str[6] = "SLEEP";
char* pointer = &(str[1]);
printf("%s\n", pointer);
```

If you are using a `std::string` instead of a raw `char` buffer (like you should be), then under C++11 `std::string` is guaranteed to have contiguous storage (21.4.1/5) with an appended NUL terminator (21.4.7.1/1):

```
std::string str = "SLEEP";
const char* pointer = &str[1];
```

These guarantees are new to C++11 -- C++03 makes no such guarantees.  However all implementations I'm aware of do in fact use contigious storage with an appended NUL terminator.  They do this because `c_str()` is required to return a `const` pointer to a C-style string.  If you want a solution that is guaranteed to be compliant in C++03, then `std::vector` makes the same contiguity guarantee, even in C++03, but of course there you must apply the NUL terminator on your own:

```
std::string load = "SLEEP";
vector <char> str;
copy (load.begin(), load.end(), back_inserter (str));
load.push_back ('\0'); // Appended NUL terminator
const char* pointer = &str [1];
```

But now we're talking about making copies, obviously.

Comment: I added one to string address, see `"SLEEP"[1]` == `'L'`, or `"SLEEP"[1]` == `*("SLEEP" + 1)` so for address of `"SLEEP"[1]` I did, `"SLEEP" + 1`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, It's valid, just not as apparent to most people.

Comment: @chris:  It's valid, but not at all resemblant to what the original question suggested was the desired code.  Hence my "wait, what?"

Comment: @chris, John I means by this is [this code](http://codepad.org/uoG5u70Y) I written in C, but I wish to add an answer here in C++

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:  So you're asking me if the code you want to post as an answer is technicall correct before you risk the downvotes by posting it yourself?  Weak sauce.

Comment: @JohnDibling Is the address-of on a `std::string` guaranteed to return the address of the contiguous data section? And not for instance its length if its the first member in the class?

Comment: @JohnDibling because question is taged to C, I might post this answer as I know (I given my working code link). I just wanted to confirm about c++. I didn't post an answer because I came late. and OP has already reasonable answers. Thanks for your time John, you answer is good.

Comment: @RedX:  `string::operator[]` returns a reference to the element.  Taking the address of that reference will yield a pointer to that element.  So, yes.

Comment: "However all implementations I'm aware of do in fact use contigious storage." - the question's about string suffixes, so both contiguous *and NUL terminated* are needed, and neither guaranteed in C++03 sans `.c_str()`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan  Could you explain the usage of  count<< "SLEEP" + 1;

Comment: @BlackMamba check my comment to question I given a link

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string s("SLEEP");
  std::cout << &s[1] << std::endl;
}
```

This is guaranteed to work in C++11. In C++03, no such guarantees exist, since implementations are allowed to use *copy on write* (COW). But I don't recall working with an implementation where this didn't work. If you use C++03 and need the guarantee, you will can use the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
std::cout << &s.c_str()[1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Works for sure in C++11 :)

Comment: Not guaranteed in C++03.

Comment: @JohnDibling Thanks, I added a line about that. I tend to think in C++11 on SO, to compensate for not being able to use it at work.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan not really, because it is dealing with an `std::string`, not a string literal. I interpret the question to be about `std::string`, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: `std::string::operator[]` is not guaranteed to be contiguous (but practically always is), however `std::string::c_str()` is guaranteed, so you could use `s.c_str() + 1`  if you don't want to use `&s[1]`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I know what you meant. I am talking about `std::string` here, so what you are showing is not equivalent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's a very good point, which I somehow managed to miss. I added a version using `c_str()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: it's not *just* a question of contiguous - in C++03 it's not guaranteed to be NUL terminated either.  Anyway, c_str() is the *only* solution for C++03 that doesn't explicitly copy, and it's still allowed to create a copy if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the array method if you want.
The example I give is C++.

for example MyStr[0] is the pointer to the first element.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string MyStr="abc";
    std::cout<<&MyStr[1];
}
```

output: bc

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string reference class. A string reference class provides string-like functionality but doesn't actually own the underlying storage.

Here's an example using the Boost `string_ref` class (found in [Boost.Utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    string str = "SLEEP";
    cout << "str: " << str << endl;
    boost::string_ref sr1(str);
    cout << "sr1: " << sr1 << endl;
    boost::string_ref sr2 = sr1.substr(1);
    cout << "sr2: " << sr2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: there in only one actual instance of the string "SLEEP". `sr1` and `sr2` are string references into `str`.